# URL Rewriting on Apache server causes 404 error page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

A few weeks ago I was trying url rewriting on my shared host. It was working for a while, but nowadays it seems to be broke. I don't know what the problem is and I can't solve it by myself. Hope you could help, guys.

This is the plan. I want to delete the extension in the url (e.g. 'file.html' or 'file.php') to only the filename (e.g. 'file'). My code is the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^index/(.*)/$ index.php?page=$1
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L] 
  ErrorDocument 404 404.php
  ErrorDocument 403 403.php
  ErrorDocument 401 401.php
</IfModule>
```

One extended note: this .htcaccess file is in the directory 'portfolio'. The root has another .htcaccess file which is the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase / 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Maybe it is something obvious, but I couldn't find what the problem is. I did try 'RewriteBase /website/', 'RewriteBase /', 'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f' and 'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d' in the first .htaccess file, but that doesn't work.

Comment: What url are you trying to go to?

Comment: I try to modify files names in the same directory. It is not necessary to go to a specific url.

Comment: What URL are you going to that you are getting a 404?

Comment: In the same directory. So: when I try to go to website/index.php, it shows website/404.php

Comment: Have you already changed your links to point to `file` and not `file.html`? Is your "portfolio" subsite dependent on your root .htaccess file?

Comment: No, it is nit dependent. In other words, it could run on another site as well without the current root folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have these rules in `/portfolio/.htaccess`

```
ErrorDocument 404 404.php
ErrorDocument 403 403.php
ErrorDocument 401 401.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /portfolio/

RewriteRule ^index/(.+?)/$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/portfolio/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [L] 

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Your rules for adding `.php` or `.html` need to have a `RewriteCond` to check whether corresponding files exist in your `portfolio` directory.

Comment: Thanks for your help! However, this does not work. The 404 error page still pops up.

Comment: All the URL's, except index.php, are causing the 404. So when I want to go to website/a or website/b it Always shows a 404. However, when I go to website/a.php it shows the page correctly.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean :)

Comment: The .htaccess is located in the directory 'portfolio'. There is a htaccess in the parent directory, the root, as well. You can see the source above.

Comment: Thanks! However, I still get a 404... Maybe it has something to do with the htaccess in the root?

Comment: No root htaccess is not read at all. There is something missing in all the information you've provided and I hate to keep asking question after question in comments.

Comment: I don't know what is missing, because I told you everything I know. Currently, I removed the errorpages and see that htaccess rewrites the file correctly. So, /portfolio/page.php is rewrited to /portfolio/page in the address bar. However, somehow it is not linked to each other, because /portfolio/page displays nothing.

Comment: Well, I know what the problem was. Obviously my hoster had some 'configuration problems'. Everything works well now. Thanks a lot for your help and time!